# Is it possible to insert standalone images in lyx

Tags: floats, lyx

I'm trying to insert an image into a document. Inserting it as:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figure_name}\caption{Description}
\end{figure}
```

Leaves an entry of type "Figure x.x.x beneath it" where x is a digit. Is it possible to insert the figure without any description below it? Only the figure as is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

To place an image in the text, same as if you place any letter in the text, just place the cursor where you want the image, and do Insert --> Graphics.

Many people seem to think that a floating environment (the `figure` environment) is required to add images, which is a misunderstanding.